# azure VM restoring as it was a week before

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I created Windows 2012 VM on azure. I did something wrong in server and suddenly behaving strange. I would like to restore server as it was a week before. Can you do that if yes how can we do it?

Comment: Is this not right platform ?

Comment: Have you backup your VM a week before? or take a snapshot at that time? If no, we can't restore it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way of doing it unless you've configured backup (or did a snapshot) for the VM. By default VM's are not backed up.

Comment: Thank you it helped